# Save checkbox values to database in YII

Tags: yii

I am a newbie to YII.

I have generated a crud form for contactlist. I have also generated checkboxes using widget for "manage contactlist". So, this checkbox code was written in admin.php page. All I want to do is saving these checked values now to database on clicking some submit button in "manage contactlist.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can choose type of checkbook field in database as (tiny-int) and in the form use this code

`<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Active'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'Active'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Active'); ?>
</div>`

Comment: I have generated the checkboxes using a widget

 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id'=>'contact-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
 'columns'=>array(
  'active',
  'econtact',
  'fname',
  'lname',
  'email',
  'mobile',
  'address',
  array(
   'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
  ),
 ),
));

Comment: you created the model with crud?? if you created, in the create.php in the view file you should change label to check-box and if you select the check-box, field in database get value of 1 and if you do not select the checkbook,field in database get value of 0.do you understand?

Comment: I think I haven't explained my que clearly....
I have generated a crud form for contactlist. I have also generated checkboxes using widget for "manage contactlist". So, this checkbox code was written in admin.php page. All I want to do is saving these checked values now to database on clicking some submit button in "manage contactlist".

Comment: My dear it is better you write this last comment on your question

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cserializebehavior/) will be useful if you want to store it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 3 things here 1) A checkbox that picks out the IDs using CCheckBoxColumn and then 2) Ajax call to pick out the data from it. Take a look at [CHtml:AjaxButton](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml) for more. 3) A controller method to process the POST values sent via the Ajax call.

**In your Gridview widget:**

```
<?php $gridWidget = $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'name-your-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'id' => 'example-check-boxes',
            'selectableRows'=>100 //Max Selectable number of rows           
            ),
..... ?>
```

**Later in your Admin view's AJAX call:**

```
'data'=> 'js:{theIds : ($.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("name-your-grid","example-check-boxes").toString())}',
```